# Mass insert on hook_install()

Tags: installation

I have a table with 4 columns that I need to be populated with ~200 rows of data in `hook_install()` via `db_insert()`.

The problem is that if I mass-insert them, the install fails with `PDOException` and no other details about the error.

If I insert 10-15 rows at once, the module installs successfully and also the data is in the database. It seems that the installer cannot handle that much inserts at once, or am I wrong?

The code looks like this:

`foreach ($values as $record) {
        $query->values($record);
        db_insert('courses_modules')->fields($record)->execute();
}
$query->execute();`

Where `$values` is an array of rows like:

`array('mid' => 1, 'cid' => 1, 'code' => 'XX', 'name' => 'Module name'),
array('mid' => 2, 'cid' => 1, 'code' => 'XY', 'name' => 'Module name'),
...`

Yes, the schema is created corectly at the time of the insert (because as I said, a few rows can be inserted, but not all).

I also tried `db_insert()->fields()->execute()` for each row.

Thank you!